# Why does not work with lambda with template

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++20

```
auto bind2nd = [] < auto func_object,auto second_arg>(){
    return [=](auto&& first_arg){
        return func_object(first_arg,second_arg);
    };
};

auto h =bind2nd.template operator()<std::greater<int>(),5>();
```

compiler result:

```
<source>:9:60: error: no matching function for call to '<lambda()>::operator()<std::greater<int>(), 5>()'

    9 | auto x =bind2nd.template operator()<std::greater<int>(),5>();

      |                                                            ^

<source>:3:16: note: candidate: 'template<auto func_object, auto second_arg> <lambda()>'

    3 | auto bind2nd = [] < auto func_object,auto second_arg>(){

      |                ^

<source>:3:16: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:

<source>:9:60: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for 'template<auto func_object, auto second_arg> <lambda()>'

    9 | auto x =bind2nd.template operator()<std::greater<int>(),5>();

      |                                                            ^

<source>:9:60: note:   expected a constant of type 'auto', got 'std::greater<int>()'

<source>:9:60: note:   ambiguous template argument for non-type template parameter is treated as function type
```

I want to use lambda with template and it does not work.

But I can run that :

```
auto x =[]<auto t>(){
    return t;
};

auto test = []<auto func_object,auto second_arg>(){
    return [=](auto&& first_arg){
        return func_object.template operator()<second_arg>();
    };
};
auto z =test.template operator()<x,5>();

int main(){
    std::cout<<z(5);
}
```

It will print 5.

What's the right way to use lambda with template and how to fix this problem?

Comment: I don’t think it’s guaranteed that `std::greater` is usable as a non-type template argument type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a template argument `std::greater<int>()` is parsed as a function type (a function that takes no arguments and returns the class type `std::greater<int>`). This is where you can use curly brackets to help the compiler differentiate:

```
auto h = bind2nd.template operator()<std::greater<int>{}, 5>();
```